# Visual Studio Code does not save files on a remote server

Tags: visual-studio, ftp

The Nautilus is connected via FTP to a remote server.
Then, I open the desired folder in the Visual Studio Code.
Folder opens correctly. IDE receives the entire directory structure and files.

```
ftp://admin@91.225.136.204/www/example.com/
```

I open the file I needed. It opens correctly - IDE receives the contents of the file.

Correctly it creates a new file.

I am making changes to the file. Preserved. Then IDE gives an error
"Could not save" test.txt ": A system error occurred (ESPIPE: invalid seek, write)".

At the same time a similar action with the same files in Sublime Text error causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision and discussion of the problem in the exclusion on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6854)